# Where are WildFly Openshift Image Streams

Tags: openshift, wildfly

when loading my image streams with:

```
oc get is -n openshift
```

I can see sometimes the Wildfly image stream is not included in the list. Not sure if it's a temporary network issue or not.
In any case, I wanted to ask if the wildfly image stream available somewhere on github, so that I can force reloading it with:

```
oc process -f [stream].json
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Wildfly image streams are a part of:

- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/openshift/origin/master/examples/image-streams/image-streams-centos7.json

As an admin, you can load that if not already loaded using:

```
oc create -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/openshift/origin/master/examples/image-streams/image-streams-centos7.json -n openshift
```

or use:

```
oc apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/openshift/origin/master/examples/image-streams/image-streams-centos7.json -n openshift
```

if not sure if present if for some reason you accidentally deleted some but not all.

Once loaded they should not disappear unless you are working in the 'openshift' namespace by mistake and delete them. You should never work in the 'openshift' namespace except to load image streams or templates you want accessible to all projects.

Comment: Thank you very much. That helps a lot!